# PsLookupProcessByProcessId with DWORD pid? Parameter 1 requires HANDLE?

Tags: c, driver, wdk, wdf

How do I go about using the function PsLookupProcessByProcessId() with a process id (DWORD pid) that I obtained from user-space?

I coded a user-space c++ application that gets the process id of another application (calc.exe for example) and using DeviceIoControl I can successfully send to the driver the pid through a struct I created.

```
DbgPrint("PID received : %i", pInp->pid);
```

Prints out the correct pid for the process.
But when doing:

```
 PsLookupProcessByProcessId(pInp->pid, eProcess);
```

I receive the warning:

> C4022: 'PsLookupProcessByProcessId': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1

The warning gets treated as an error and vs wont let me compile.
I looked up the documentation for 'PsLookupProcessByProcessId' and it says it requires a 'handle' for the first parameter. So, in that case, how would I go about getting the handle with a DWORD pid sent from the user-space application?

Comment: You need to declare `pInp->pid` to be of type `HANDLE`. The second parameter looks to be wrong too. You need to pass the address of your `PEPROCESS` variable surely.

Comment: @ThePara that's a user mode function. This is a kernel mode question.

Answer (score 1):

```
PEPROCESS eProcess = NULL; 
PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)pInp->pid, &eProcess);
```

"Specifies the process ID of the process." -> HANDLE could sound confusing, in this case it's not a true "HANDLE" object.